# Textarea dinâmico ao editar formulário

Tags: javascript, css

Vou tentar explicar o meu problema. Inicialmente consulto a informação, onde o textarea ajusta automaticamente o tamanho de acordo com o texto que retorna da base de dados. Estou a fazer desta forma:

```js
$(".area").on('keyup input keypress keydown change', function(e) {
    var tamanhoMin =  $(this).attr('rows') * $(this).css('line-height').replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, '');
    $(this).css({'height': 'auto'});
    var novoTamanho = this.scrollHeight + parseFloat($(this).css("borderTopWidth")) + parseFloat($(this).css("borderBottomWidth"));
    if (tamanhoMin > novoTamanho) novoTamanho = tamanhoMin;
    $(this).css({'height': novoTamanho});
}).css({
    'overflow':'hidden', 
    'resize':'none'
}).delay(0).show(0, function() {
    var el = $(this);
    setTimeout(function () {
        el.trigger('keyup');
    }, 100);        
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal-header">   
<h4 class="modal-title">IDENTIFICAÇÃO</h4>  
<a style="float:right" type="button" name="edit" id="'.$row["codigo"].'" data-toggle="modal" href="#ad_Modaleditar" class="btn btn-primary edit_anamnese">Editar</a>     
</div>  
<form id="insert_form1">
<div class="row clearfix">
<div class="col_half">
<label>O que pode Despoletar a Crise/Descompensação</label>
<div class="textarea_field"> <span><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-comment"></i></span>
<textarea style="padding-left:35px" class="form-control area" readonly="true">1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
</textarea>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

Até aqui tudo bem.

Depois quando clico no botão editar abre um novo formulário, que recebe a informação para ser editado, mas aqui o textarea não ajusta automaticamente:

```
<div class="col_half">
<label>O que pode Despoletar a Crise/Descompensação</label>
<div class="textarea_field"> <span><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-comment"></i></span>
<textarea style="padding-left:35px" class="form-control area1" id="Despoletar" name="Despoletar"></textarea>
</div>
</div>
```

js:

```
$(".area1").on('keyup input keypress keydown change', function(e) {
var tamanhoMin1 =  $(this).attr('rows') * $(this).css('line-height').replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, '');
$(this).css({'height': 'auto'});
var novoTamanho1 = this.scrollHeight + parseFloat($(this).css("borderTopWidth")) + parseFloat($(this).css("borderBottomWidth"));
if (tamanhoMin1 > novoTamanho1) novoTamanho1 = tamanhoMin1;
$(this).css({'height': novoTamanho1});
}).css({
    'overflow':'hidden', 
    'resize':'none'
}).delay(0).show(0, function() {
    var el1 = $(this);
    setTimeout(function () {
        el1.trigger('keyup');
    }, 100);        
});
```

e fica desta forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Podem ajudar a identificar o problema?

Comment: Use `$(document).on('keyup input keypress keydown change', '.area1', function(e) {`. Acho que o problema é esse. Se não for isso, dá um aviso aqui.

Comment: @Sam alterando a linha que indicou recebo o erro `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'display' of undefined`

Comment: Verdade. Vou dar uma olhada aqui. Mas, tirando esse erro, o textarea funcionou como esperado?

Comment: @Sam, sim o textarea funciona como espelho, mas não ajusta na altura

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que elementos adicionados dinamicamente ao DOM não são escutados pelos eventos já criados.

Você terá que usar a forma delegada dos eventos através do objeto `document`:

```
$(document)
.on('keyup input keypress keydown change', '.area1', function(e) {
// resto do código
```

Com isso, você deverá usar outro seletor com a classe `.area1` para disparar o `delay` e o `show`:

```
$(".area1")
.delay(0)
.show(0, function() {
    var el1 = $(this);
    setTimeout(function () {
        el1.trigger('keyup');
    }, 100);        
});
```

Esse trecho não faz muito sentido:

```
.css({
    'overflow':'hidden', 
    'resize':'none'
})
```

Ou você coloca direto no CSS:

```
.area1{
   display: none;
   overflow: hidden;
   resize: none;
}
```

Ou então no segundo seletor que coloquei acima:

```
$(".area1")
.css({
   'overflow':'hidden', 
   'resize':'none'
})
.delay(0)
.show(0, function() {
    var el1 = $(this);
    setTimeout(function () {
        el1.trigger('keyup');
    }, 100);        
});
```

> Só que se você colocar no seletor, os novos elementos com `.area1` não
>   serão afetados. Por isso é melhor colocar direto no CSS.

**O código completo ficará assim:**

CSS (parte do `.area1`):

```
.area1{
   display: none;
   overflow: hidden;
   resize: none;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document)
.on('keyup input keypress keydown change', '.area1', function(e) {
   var tamanhoMin1 =  $(this).attr('rows') * $(this).css('line-height').replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, '');
   $(this)
   .css({'height': 'auto'});

   var novoTamanho1 = this.scrollHeight + parseFloat($(this).css("borderTopWidth")) + parseFloat($(this).css("borderBottomWidth"));
   if (tamanhoMin1 > novoTamanho1) novoTamanho1 = tamanhoMin1;
   $(this).css({'height': novoTamanho1});
});

$(".area1")
.delay(0)
.show(0, function() {
    var el1 = $(this);
    setTimeout(function () {
        el1.trigger('keyup');
    }, 100);        
});
```

## Detalhe

Ao criar novos textareas é preciso disparar o evento `keyup` com `$(".area1:last").trigger('keyup');` (dispara o evento no último textarea criado).

Comment: fica com um problema, fica como na imagem que coloco na pergunta: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMfO9.jpg). Só ajusta o textarea depois de ter uma acção dentro do textarea, como por exemplo: clicar no enter ou colocar uma letra. Ao ter essa acção o textarea ajusta, mas devia ajustar logo ao abrir

Comment: Entendi. Você precisa disparar o trigger assim que o novo textarea é adicionado.

Comment: neste caso como posso disparar o trigger ao tempo que abro o novo formulário

Comment: Coloque no final da função que abre o novo formulário um `$(".area1:last").trigger('keyup');`